# Appium with Selenium Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium, appium

The below code seems to be working fine in one device but while trying with another device ( that has the same android version ) the click happens at another location

```
list = (AndroidElement)driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("+ "new UiSelector().text(\"Display\"))"));
list.click();
```

The above code when we try with one device is clicking on "display" which is **as** **expected**

[image]

While we try it with another device its clicking at a different location

[image]

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation please?

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: What is the error with another device?

Comment: It is clicking on the wrong element I.e instead of "kill switch url(optional)" Another element is getting selected in another device.

Comment: @ManasaG - can u tell which two devices u r using, there may be difference in screen size of both devices..

Comment: Do you have to use AndroidUIAutomator? Can you use another locating strategy, i.e. id or xpath? Also, page source would be helpful.

Comment: As suggested earlier try to use different location strategy and also try to scroll the screen to get relative xpath.Yes screen size does matter depending on locator strategy as locator might not be visible.You can also try record and play and try to modufy the code accordingly.

Comment: What about the Xpath in second device, is it the same?